# How do I assign a nested JSON-Object to a simple class, where the nested objects get their own field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following JSON Object:

```
{
    "header": {"bookid": 43, "title" : "MyTitle", "author" : "John Doe"},
    "content" : "Book Content"
}
```

and I want to create a book object (see models.py) out of this json object.
I am also using the serializer of the DRF that has to validate the json object first and then it has to create the book object, which is then saved into a database. However only the content field, gets its data. The header data has somehow to be preprocessed (because of its child object). How would one usually do that? In the serializer? or before it gets passed to the serializer?

#### models.py

```
class Books:
    bookid = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    title = models.Charfield(max_length=50, default='')
    author = models.Charfield(max_length=50, default='')
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
```

#### serializers.py

```
class BooksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = '__all__'
        
        
    @staticmethod
    def create(validated_data):
        return Books.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

#### database entries

```
id      bookid      title       author      content
5       0           <empty>     <empty>     Book Content
```

#### expected database entries

```
id      bookid      title       author      content
5       43          MyTitle     John Doe    Book Content
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change your json object to

```
{ "bookid": 43, "title" : "MyTitle", "author" : "John Doe", "content" : "Book Content"}
```

if u use json object above, serializers will create model like you expected..
If you want not change json object, you can pass json object to serializer argument like this,

```
serializer = CommentSerializer(data={'email': 'foobar', 'content': 'baz'})
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, indeed that is a solution. however, i have to edit the object, which i actually wanted to avoid. If there are no more suggestions from the community, I will go by your solution.